# How to add specific boot to grub menu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

How can I add a specific boot partition (fat32) to the grub menu for Ubuntu?

Comment: UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation   And if using UEFI, you need to have drive in gpt partitioning, not old MBR(msdos). But changing from MBR to gpt may totally erase entire drive.

Comment: I already have the EFI fat32 Gpt partition, need to make it visible on grub menu its for hackintosh Os

Comment: This is an Ubuntu and its official flavors support site.